# How is the memory unpinned in Memory<T>.Span?

Tags: c#, memory-management, heap-memory

I believe that following two pieces of code should be equivalent:

```
// first example
string s = "Hello memmory";
ReadOnlyMemory<char> memory = s.AsMemory();
using (MemoryHandle pin = memory.Pin())
{
    Span<char> span = new Span<char>(pin.Pointer, 1);
    Console.WriteLine(span[0]);
}

// second example
ReadOnlySpan<char> span2 = memory.Span;
Console.WriteLine(span2[0]);
```

Both codes will print "H".

What I don't understand is where is the unpinning of memory in the second example.

As I understand it string is allocated on Heap, `MemoryHandle` pinn it and create Span from the pointer. `MemoryHandle.Dispose` unpin memory back.

I believe that `memory.Span` must pin the memory as well, otherwise span couldn't accessing the pointer. But how is the memory unpinned in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last assumption is incorrect: `memory.Span` does not need to pin the memory, as the garbage collector is aware of its underlying reference. Pinning is independently available in case you would like to pass the pointer to a native API.

Answer (score 1):

A Span only lives on the stack of the current method thread and not on the Heap of it therefore will it be alive as long as you using it there. So far so clear.

Now the funny part:

The clear truth is that the result of `memory.Span` is not pinned but only referenced by using the `ref T` inside the `Span<T>` what is .nets idea of managed pointers that are also observed by the GarbageCollector.

As long as your Memory lives, your span will too and by this your Span.

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-struct-types